# Food Safety: Do I have to boil pork and then fry it?

Tags: food-safety, temperature, pork

I know that I should cook pork at 63 °C and without rinsing to avoid cross-contamination. My question is the following; I want to fry pork chops: Does this means I have to boil the pork in water until that temperature and then fry or just toss it into the oil and wait until it reaches that temp? And if I don't rinse it, does it mean the pork just goes with the blood to the boiler or frying pan?

Sorry for the stupid question, but I'm really a noob at cooking and everyone adviced me to just rinse it with vinegar.

Comment: I strongly recommend you find a recipe for fried pork chops from a reputable website like [this](http://thepioneerwoman.com/cooking/simple-pan-fried-pork-chops/) This will walk you through the entire process. It even has step-by-step photos!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you do not. A pork chop can be safely cooked by only frying it. That doesn't mean that if you fry a pork chop it's guaranteed to be safe. You can use a meat thermometer to see if the inside has reached 63 (or whatever recommend temperature you're aiming for), and don't take it out of the pan until it does. (Note you are not cooking it **at** 63, you are cooking it **to** 63.)

When the chop is very thick, you might find it too seared on the outside by the time it gets to temp in the middle. A way around that is to sear both sides and then put it in the oven. Again you use the thermometer to be sure it is cooked.

I won't say that no-one ever boils pork. Many people boil (or more accurately, simmer) ribs for a long time, to break down the connective tissue, before quickly glazing them on a grill. But boiling a pork chop is pretty unusual.

I don't rinse pork before I cook it. Many cultures have a tradition of rinsing meat with water, vinegar, or lemon before cooking it. Modern advice is that this isn't needed. It won't hurt the pork if you do, but it's possible you could spread contamination through your sink or wherever the water ends up. That's why people advise you to skip any kind of rinsing.

As a final note, I don't add oil when I fry a pork chop. I don't "toss it into the oil" I put it in a pan - nonstick, or a heavy stainless steel. Don't turn it too often: it will release from the pan as it cooks.